# magento 2 custom component at checkout-step-shipping as shipping address child

Tags: checkout, uicomponent, magento2.2.2, knockoutjs

I trying to add a custom template @ checkout between form customer login and shipping address **inside div id="checkout-step-shipping"**  there are 2 forms :
[image]

I've tried a few thing like 'before-form' etc.. I've manage to add before and after everything following this :https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html
But Not able to add in between!
Here is my xml :

```
...<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="MYCUSTOMHTML" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/MYCUSTOMCOMPONENT</item>
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>...
```

Here is my component :

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'ko'
],
function (Component, $, stepNavigator, quote, alert, modal, ko) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/MYCUSTOMCOMPONENT'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            console.log('LOADED!');
        }
    })
}
```

);

My html:

```
<div>TEST TEST TESTE</div>
```

This works I console.log `LOADED` but the html does not gets added!

Does anyone have any idea I ma not sure why the html not showing up as the component loads! any help Appreciate thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it!  I was actually missing ** displayArea** before-form

but I was trying :

```
       ...<item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="MYCUSTOMHTML" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/MYCUSTOMCOMPONENT</item>
                       <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                     </item>
                </item>   
            </item>
        </item>...
```

And I should be

```
...<item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="MYCUSTOMHTML" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/MYCUSTOMCOMPONENT</item>
                   <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-form</item>
             </item>
        </item>   
    </item>
</item>...
```